# Can't upload any 100MB+ file to my DigitalOcean droplet - I get timeouts

Tags: digitalocean

I have a droplet I set a password for and set FileZilla to access it.  FileZilla can view the directories on it and create a directory on it.

I have some video files on my local machine, they are e.g. 100MB+

When I try to send the files over I get issues so I tried just one file.

If I try to copy the file onto Google Drive, then no problem. 138MB file transferred in 2 minutes.

But if I try with FileZilla to put the file on the droplet. Then I have problems.

After first minute still 0.1% done, from that 2318 file, then it said timeout (I set the timeout to 100 seconds). Then it continues and it says 0.5%. It basically downloads a little bit for a second, then stops, then timeouts, then tries again maybe does a bit more.

I had googled how to transfer files to my droplet and found this guide:
https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/droplets/how-to/transfer-files/
recommending FileZilla.

My SSH server has a very strong password and no SSH key, though I don't think that matters and doesn't matter for this. FileZilla could connect as I entered my droplet's password into it.

Note- I don't know what tag to use as there's no option for file transfer, so I used Ubuntu as a tag. It is an ubuntu droplet.

Comment: scp, sftp, rsync   are all popular..  some try SAMBA though that might not work over the internet 'cos some ISPs block it

Answer (score 1):

WinSCP is good, works very well. SCP(hence WinSCP) works over SSH.

I just tested it and get about 900KB/s so basically 1MB/s  so a 138MB file would take about 138sec which is between 2min and 2.5 min.  So similar speed I get transferring to google drive.  And that's dependent on my upload speed which is not more than 1MB/s  So WinSCP works perfectly.  Not sure what was going wrong with FileZilla. But WinSCP is well designed and just better.